# Multi Module layout set up in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have created new project in Zend and created layout. However, I have problem with CSS directory installation. If I have an action inside the control. The directory keep changing

For example:

For this url: localhost:88zendproject/public/ it is ok

But for this http://localhost:88/zendproject/public/account/
the directory of the css becomes
http://localhost:88/zendproject/public/account/css/bootstrap.css where it adds account and change the path to css..

Could you please advice me how to properly configure layout in zend so I can use for multiple modules(Module inside module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your views / layouts, use the `BaseUrl` helper when specifying paths to static assets (images, CSS, JS, etc). For example

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()
    ->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('css/bootstrap.css')) ?>
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl